# Templates and STL Containers

Tags: c++, templates, stl, containers

```
template<typename T>
    class Foo {
        template<???>
        Foo(Container<T> c) {
        }
    };
...
//this can't be changed
std::vector<int> vec;
Foo<int> foo1(vec);
std::list<double> list;
Foo<double> foo2(list);
```

Hmmm?

Comment: What for? Why the strange requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't at all clear to me what you are asking for. I think you may need to edit your question to be more specific and more complete.

Until then, your program will compile just fine if you do this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>

template <typename T>
    class Foo {
    public:
        template<typename T1>
        Foo(T1 c) {
        }
    };

std::vector<int> vec;
Foo<int> foo1(vec);

std::list<double> list;
Foo<double> foo2(list);
```

Comment: Nice and simple. I'm satisfied. Thank you.

Comment: @sam: Maybe you could clarify your question so we can stop you from writing bad code...

Answer (score 3):

It's difficult to tel what you want to achieve with this, but a simple template as below should do the trick:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo 
{
    Foo(std::vector<T> const& v) 
    {
        // initialize from vector
    }
    Foo(std::list<T> const& l) 
    {
        // initialize from list
    }
};

...

std::vector<int> vec;
Foo<int> foo1(vec);
std::list<double> list;
Foo<double> foo2(list);
```

Comment: Thank you. But I need more generalization for unknown classes like MyClass<type>.